# Drawing a pizza pie shape in turtle

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

We were assigned to make a pizza using user-inputted amount of slices, but I can't figure out how to tilt the slice.

```
import turtle

window = turtle.Screen()
window.bgcolor("lightgreen")  
slice = turtle.Turtle() 
slice.color("orange")

slice_amount = int(input("How many slices do you want to make? "))

if slice_amount == slice_amount:
  slice.tilt(360/slice_amount)
  def pizza(angle, radius, t):
    t.begin_fill()
    t.setheading((180 - angle) / 2)
    t.forward(radius)
    t.setheading(-0.5 * angle + 180)
    t.circle(radius, angle)
    t.goto(0, 0)
    t.end_fill()
  
    for i in range(slice_amount -1):
      t.begin_fill()
      t.setheading((180 - angle) / 2)
      t.forward(radius)
      t.setheading(-0.5 * angle + 180)
      t.circle(radius, angle)
      t.goto(0, 0)
      t.end_fill()
  pizza(360/slice_amount, 100, slice)
  
turtle.done()
```

I tried to put the whole function in an `if` statement but that didn't help.

Comment: Change the angle after you draw each slice in your `for` loop.

Answer (score 1):

When you're drawing shapes around a circle, the typical approach is to:

1. draw a shape
2. move back to the origin
3. point the turtle in the direction of the next shape
4. go back to step 1

You're missing step 3, positioning the turtle so it's ready to draw the next thing. Without this step, it winds up repeatedly drawing the same shape over and over.

One approach is to set the heading to point at the origin before `goto(0, 0)`, then rotate 180 degrees to point directly at the line the turtle has just drawn to close the last pie slice.

```py
from turtle import Turtle

n = 6
radius = 100
angle = 360 / n
t = Turtle()

for i in range(n):
    t.color(i / n, 0, 0)
    t.begin_fill()
    t.forward(radius)
    t.left(90)
    t.circle(radius, angle)
    t.setheading(t.towards(0, 0))
    t.goto(0, 0)
    t.left(180)
    t.end_fill()

t.getscreen().exitonclick()
```

Another option is to use your `i` to set the heading for each slice:

```py
# ...

for i in range(n):
    t.setheading(i * angle)
    t.color(i / n, 0, 0)
    t.begin_fill()
    t.forward(radius)
    t.left(90)
    t.circle(radius, angle)
    t.goto(0, 0)
    t.end_fill()

# ...
```

When you're working on getting your logic correct, try to avoid functions and `input()`. Adding those things too soon adds complexity that gets in the way of your logic and slows down experimentation. Once you've ensured correctness, then you can split logic into functions and add extra features like user interaction.

Additionally, `slice()` is a builtin function in Python, so pick a different name for your variable to avoid overwriting it.

`if slice_amount == slice_amount:` does nothing so you can remove that.